# How to find out which quartile a value lies in excel

Tags: excel

I have the below data:

```
22.43
6.27
8.34
0
14.28
0.81
2.31
27.23
4.46
0.3
```

From this I am calculating the quartiles as below:

```
min 25th    50th    75th    MaX
0   1.185   5.365   12.795  27.23

1st Quartile.               
    2nd Quartile.           
        3rd Quartile.       
            4th Quartile.
```

Now for each value I need to find out which quartile it lies in.
So expected output.

```
22.43   4th Quartile
6.27    3rd Quartile
8.34    3rd Quartile
0       1st Quartile
14.28   4th Quartile
0.81    1st Quartile
2.31    2nd Quartile
27.23   4th Quartile
4.46    2nd Quartile
0.3     1st Quartile
```

A snapshot of my excel sheet:

[image]

Can someone please help me in doing this in excel.

Comment: This could be done with nested [IF](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-if-function) functions: `= if (and(r >= p0, r < p1), "1st", if (and (r >= p1, r < 0), "2nd", ..` , but that seems not like an Excel Master approach :}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a LOOKUP construct like below. Assuming your data is in cell A2, following formula should work for you.

`=LOOKUP(A2,{0,1.185,5.365,12.795},{"1st","2nd","3rd","4th"})&" Quartile"`

Answer (score 0):

If your array starts in A1, in D2 and copied across:

```
=QUARTILE($A1:$A10,COLUMN()-4)
```

Then use an HLOOKUP without its fourth parameter.